# Custom Views or inflated layouts?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view

**Background information:**

I'm working on a small app for myself and a few friends, and it contains a few `ListViews` with items based on custom XML layouts. The layouts are somewhat heavy - a few `ImageViews`, `TextViews`, a `LinearLayout` and a `RelativeLayout` - so I started thinking about performance. I'm not personally experiencing any performance issues, but I know that some of my friends, who'll be using the app, don't have high-end phones and that they might have issues with these layouts.

I remember watching a video presentation regarding performance in Android, and I recall Romain Guy mentioning something about custom `Views` being better for performance than constantly inflating custom XML layouts. I believe the context was the early development of the Gmail application (around Android 1.5, I believe), where each item of the `Listview` was rather complex.

It's probably worth pointing out that I'm reusing `Views` in my application, and that I'm using the `ViewHolder` principle as recommended by Google.

**My question:** Is it better for performance to use custom `Views` or is it OK to inflate custom XML layouts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, then answer is "it depends" -  inflating view from XML imposes some  performance penalty ( parsing overhead )  over plain creation in code,   but also provides greater flexibility.   You should definitely reuse views whenever possible ( especially in larger lists) -  it improves scrolling performance dramatically

Comment: Cheers, Konstantin. That's more or less what I thought. I'll keep it open for more answers, but thanks so far! +1

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a custom layout instead of having a linear layouts and relative layouts it will be more beneficial for you to just create a custom layout. It's kind of like, instead of using nested linear layouts, you should just use a relative layout. If you use relative and linear and a whole bunch of views, then just coding a custom layout should be beneficial.